# How set color of BarChart in Javafx

Tags: java, colors, javafx, bar-chart, fxml

I have an app that reads file and shows a chart of number of occurrences of each letter in file (In my app file must be located at "C:/new1.txt").

I want to set the color of bar depending on selected Radio Button but it does not change the colour.How can i set colour and where do i make mistake?

[Github Link](https://github.com/berkkarabacak/odevyeni/tree/master/src/sample)

Controller Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    public BarChart<String,Number> barchart;


    @FXML
    RadioButton redbutton=new RadioButton("Red");

    @FXML
    RadioButton bluebutton=new RadioButton("Blue");


    @FXML
    ToggleGroup group=new ToggleGroup();
    public void selam(ActionEvent a){

        //Array to store number of occurrences of each letter in file
        //Ex = if exist 2 "a" and 4 "d" then counter[0]=2  and counter[3]=4
        int[] counter = new int[26];


        //Read file
        try {
            File file = new File("C:/new1.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file,"utf-8");
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray();

                for (Character karakter : chars) {
                    if(Character.isLetter(karakter)) {
                        //add to array
                        counter[karakter - 'a']++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("File does not exist");

        }

        char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        int orderofletter=0;
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        //Add number of occurrences of each letter to XY chart
        for (char c:alphabet){
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(String.valueOf(c), counter[orderofletter]));
            orderofletter++;
        }


        // CHANGE COLOR
        if(redbutton.isSelected()){
            barchart.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: red;");
            System.out.println("Red");
}

        if(bluebutton.isSelected()){
           barchart.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: blue;");
        }
        //Add xychart to barchart
        barchart.getData().addAll(series1);
            }
}
```

FXML class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane id="mainpane" fx:id="mainpane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="590.0" prefWidth="1085.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <TextField layoutY="517.0" prefHeight="67.0" prefWidth="309.0" />
        <BarChart fx:id="barchart" barGap="2.0" layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="498.0" prefWidth="1085.0" style="-fx-border-color: chartreuse;">
            <xAxis>
                <CategoryAxis endMargin="0.0" side="BOTTOM" startMargin="0.0" />
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
                <NumberAxis prefHeight="364.0" prefWidth="33.0" side="LEFT" upperBound="0.0" />
            </yAxis>
        </BarChart>
        <Button layoutX="447.0" layoutY="512.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selam" prefHeight="67.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Draw" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="bluebutton" layoutX="324.0" layoutY="551.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Blue">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="group" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </RadioButton>
      <RadioButton fx:id="redbutton" layoutX="324.0" layoutY="517.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Red" toggleGroup="$group" />
    </children>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to set the colour individually for every chart-bar:

```
barchart.getData().addAll(series1);

if (bluebutton.isSelected()) {
    barchart.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-bar")
            .forEach(n -> n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: blue;"));
}
```

Comment: It works now when i first click "Draw button".But if i click it again(which runs selam(ActionEvent a) again ) it keeps drawing in random colors.Any ideas why?

Comment: If you click again, another chart bar is drawn besides the blue one. So you need to set the color for other chart bars, too. In my example, I set it for `.default-color0.chart-bar`, but there is also `.default-color1.chart-bar` and so forth.